# Load "subtemplate" within template in django (and pass context into that template)

Tags: django

New to web dev. Is there a way to load a django template within another template (based on user actions, eg. a button click) and still be able to use the context object from the view that loaded the overall template?

Eg. I have a template that loads a series of (semantic UI) cards. Would like to be able to click on a card and (without "switching screens") load a sub-template to replace the set of cards that remembers the value of some of the text on the card (or maybe the card's `name=` attribute) (which is based on some context variables brought in by the view that loaded the template) which would then be used in the newly loaded subtempate.

** If there a more django-ish way to do this kind of behavior, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean with *dynamic*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem removed that word, as the question may be a bit clearer without it (honestly I did not really know exactly what I meant either).